# Inconsistent Responses from AWS EKS Microservices Behind ALB Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

Hello,

I'm encountering an issue with my microservices deployed on AWS Elastic Kubernetes Service (EKS) and exposed through an Application Load Balancer (ALB) Ingress. I'm facing inconsistent responses when making requests to my microservices, and I'm seeking guidance on troubleshooting and resolving this issue.

My microservice is deployed on AWS EKS and is accessible through an ALB Ingress. The problem arises when I make requests to the service's URL. Sometimes, I receive the expected response, while other times, I encounter an error page indicating "Cannot POST /trello/register/getInstallationUrl."

I've already reviewed my Kubernetes Ingress configuration to ensure proper request routing. Additionally, I've checked the health of the instances or pods behind the ALB to ensure they are in good health. Furthermore, I've closely monitored the running status of my microservices within EKS, ensuring that they are operational.

Comment: Have you looked at your container logs? Is the request making it to your app? You could also enable logging at the load balancer or adding tracing, e.g. X-Ray.